# How can use BSDS500 benchmark?

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, mex, image-segmentation

I want to use the [Berkeley Segmentation Data Set and Benchmarks 500 (BSDS500)](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html#bsds500) for my segmentation algorithm.

When I run `build.m` in the source files, I get an error about "`sys/times.h` doesn't exist in MSVC". There is also another header file that needs `ieee754.h`.

I googled a lot and find that running the code on Linux may could help, But I doubt. Now I have some questions:

- Is there a way to use `sys/times.h` and `ieee754.h` in Windows? Does MinGW have these header files?
- Has someone run BSDS500 benchmark on windows? How?

Comment: @Bebs: The `build.m` file does sound like Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that comes with BSDS500 is written for MATLAB on Linux or MacOS (these are the POSIX-compatible systems that MATLAB runs on).

If you are on Windows, you can try to use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) to build these binaries. Cygwin adds a POSIX layer in Windows. MinGW by itself doesn't do this, it only provides the GNU tools on Windows. The file `sys/times.h` is defined in the POSIX standard.

But, IMO, you're better off switching to Linux. Not just for BSDS500, but for everything else too... :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Need to try this solution, but did you use bsds500 on windows by this solution?

Comment: @pedram64: No, I have not. But I have compiled other software on Windows using Cygwin, including MEX-files for MATLAB that depend on complex libraries that require a POSIX environment. Cygwin just works!